# How can I fix Master mismatch for some slides in PowerPoint 2016 presentation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, master

I have a presentation that has a Master. A bunch of slides that I copied from another deck do not adhere to the Master (for example, page numbers that are supposed to in the lower right are missing). I futzed with the Slide Master view but could not fix it. What else can I do to fix those slides? It seems the internal references to the Master in those slides are broken, so how can I fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > I have a presentation that has a Master

ALL presentations have one or more Masters.

When you copy slides from one presentation to another, you usually get a little popup gadget or a question from PPT asking whether you want to preserve the original slide's formatting or not. If you say no, the incoming slides get formatted according to the master and layout of the slide you're inserting them after (as I recall).

If you say yes, choose to preserve the original slides' formatting, then as often as not, your presentation gets another master and layout(s) added, the one from the incoming slides.

In real life, it can get more complicated than that, but let's let that be for now.

Try this:

Go to one of the newly inserted slides

On the home tab, click Layout (in the "Slides" group) and apply the layout you want for the slide (from the topmost master if there are multiples).

Click RESET to force the layout to be reapplied

Answer (score 1):

[This is a comment, not an answer. unfortunately I can't add a comment mechanism due to my reputation being <50. Would appreciate it if an admin could move this to the right place]

I have the exact same issue as in the original question. The proposed solution (the only one, at the time of writing, by Steve Rinsdberg) does not work for me. PowerPoint does not prompt me to ask whether I want to preserve the original slide's formatting or not.

I'm using PowerPoint 2019 on Windows 10, 64 bit]
[in detail: Microsoft Office Home and Business 2019 version 2202, build 14931.20132, 64 bit]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1116465)